# DMS coordinate columns to X&Y

Tags: python, coordinates, coordinate-transformation

I have one column of point coordinates in DMS of its latitude and another one of its longitude. I would like to make new columns in, where the coordinates would be expressed in x & y.
So from LAT_DMS and LON_DMS, while using Python, I would like to have new columns of X and Y.
Thanks in advance!
/S

I was finding code where you could tranform single records, but without thinking the column element in.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.